# How to do it in mysql: If id=idold THEN UPDATE status=1

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to compare two tables and then update if some logic is true,

In pseudo code:

```
SELECT * FROM users, usersold IF users.id=usersold.id THEN UPDATE users.status=1;
```

Is there a way to do it in MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE users u
SET status = 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM usersold WHERE id = u.id)
```

Alternate version:

```
UPDATE users
SET status = 1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM usersold)
```

You should test and, depending on your database, you may find one performs better than the other although I expect any decent database will optimize then to be much the same anyway.